# Protractor - Not able enter the date in android app using sendkeys

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, appium

I am trying to automate the android hybrid app using protractor. I am trying to input the date using sendkeys command, but not able to enter the date.
When I click on dob(Date of birth), it pop-ups date picker. But i am trying to send the date of birth field without date picker pop-up.

Here is my code below:

```
var dob=element(by.css('input[id="personalInfoDateOfBirth"]'));
dob.sendKeys('11/05/1981').then(function() {
    console.log('Date of birth is entered');
});
```

Kindly Advice...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> date = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker"));
    date.get(0).sendKeys("Apr");
    date.get(1).sendKeys("12");
    date.get(2).sendKeys("1990");
```

Comment: Hello Gary Thanks for the response. I am using the below code. But gives error -    var day 1 = browser.findElement(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker")).findElement(By.id("android:id/day")); day1.clear(); day1.sendKeys('05');
var mon=browser.findElement(By.id("android:id/month")); mon.clear(); mon.sendKeys("jun");
var yr=browser.findElement(By.id("android:id/year")); yr.clear(); yr.sendKeys("2005");                                          ERROR: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.className("android.widget.DatePicker")

Comment: Also tried using: var day1 = browser.findElement(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker"));     day1.get(0).sendKeys('05');     But Gets the Error: -->>     Message:
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'

Comment: on which line you are getting this error "element not found"? replace that with some other locator like xpath

Comment: I am getting error on line..browser.findElement(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker"))..... "Element not found error". Also, I tried using xpath...but still getting element not found error.    the Xpath used is :   browser.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Feb']"))...

Comment: Also, Tried to use protractor xpath, but still no success:: browser.findElement(By.xpath('//qcl-date-time-input-picker[@id="personalInfoDateOfBirth"]/label[@class="qcl-datetime-input-picker"]/div'));

Comment: Instead of passing the element by one class name, sometimes it doesnt work in appium. i have edit my answer, try by using my new answer.

Comment: Hi Gary, I tried with the above code..but does not work in protractor...While using "List<WebElement> date ="  shows invalid assignment -left hand side....... If I use only var date = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker")); date.get(0).sendKeys("Apr"); .... displays invalid "get" statement....cannot use "get" with the date object...

Comment: Also, I tried with var date = browser.findElement(By.className("android.widget.DatePicker"));  date.findElement(by.id("android:id/day")).sendKeys('Apr');  Displays error:      NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.className("android.widget.DatePicker")

Comment: I tried this as well ::::::::               var date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.DatePicker//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[0]"));  But It does not find the date picker element..... Fails in this point itself....

Comment: Hi, is there any alternative solution for the date picker wheel automation in Protractor?